# Connecting and controlling a device using a script python

Tags: python, tcp

I am trying to control a robot arm with its controller by sending to it one character via TCP/IP using python script. I already tried to use it with its own program, and it works. Now, if I connect my computer to that controller via Ethernet, and I run the python script, it doesn't give me any error, but I don't received anything considering that I programmed the controller to send a letter via TCP/IP continuously.
The robot is a RV-2F-D by Mitsubishi and the script is this one:

```
import socket
import time

BUFFER_SIZE = 4
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 
proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
print("Socket created")
c = socket.getaddrinfo("192.168.21.250",10007,proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.connect(("192.168.21.250",10007))
print("Connected to device")
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(data)
print(c)
s.close()
```

What can I do? Could you give me some tips?

Comment: You're not saving the return value of s.recv anywhere... try data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) and then print.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that part... in my script I wrote `data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` and then `print(data)`

Comment: I'd recommend reading the entire tutorial here: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/. In short, sockets aren't guaranteed to return the number of bytes you ask for. You probably want to implement a function called `recvall()` that continuously reads until it has received the number of bytes specified.

Answer (score 0):

I've use some RV (6 and 12). 
You can access the controller using ssh and ftp.
For access via TCP/IP you must configure the controller.
TCP Port and source IP address must be inserted.
Then you can use the robot, but attention he accept mxt records only.